# layout_below and weightsum of LinearLayout Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am creating `LinearLayout` in `RelativeLayout` programmatically. What I am trying to do is to assign the `weigtsum` in `LinearLayout` and want to set the `layout_above` attribute as well. The problem is `weightSum` is available in `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `layout_above` is available in `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Currently,, I am doing

```
LinearLayout ll_menu_code = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll_menu_code.setId(1001);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parmas_ll_menu_code = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);
        parmas_ll_menu_code.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
        ll_menu_code.setLayoutParams(parmas_ll_menu_code);
```

Which sets the `weightSum`. How to set the `layout_above`? What should the way to set the both attributes?

I want to create the following `xml` layout programmatically

```
<LinearLayout
                                android:layout_below="@id/ll_menu_code"
                                android:id="@+id/ll_quantity"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:weightSum="5">
```

Comment: As you said LinearLayout does not have layout_above, so you cannot set that attribute in a LinearLayout. Maybe you should tell what you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add `LinearLayout` into `RelativeLayout` programmatically, then you must create instance of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` rather than `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` since `LinearLayout` is a child to `Relativelayout`

So your code must be

```
LinearLayout ll_menu_code = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll_menu_code.setId(1001);
    ll_menu_code.setWeightSum(2f);        

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parmas_ll_menu_code = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parmas_ll_menu_code.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
    parmas_ll_menu_code.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1001);

    ll_menu_code.setLayoutParams(parmas_ll_menu_code);
```

I Hope it helps..